# sencha touch complex models

Tags: drupal, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to read entities from a Drupal Services endpoint into my Sencha Touch 2 application. The JSON output looks like this (simplified):

```
{
  nid: 1
  title: 'Test'
  body: {
    'en': [
      'This is a test.'
    ]
  }
}
```

Thats the model's coffeescript code:

```
Ext.define 'Node',
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model'

  config:
    idProperty: 'nid'

    fields: [
      { name: 'nid', type: 'integer' }
      { name: 'title', type: 'string' }
      { name: 'language', type: 'string' }
      { name: 'body', type: 'auto', convert: convertField }
    ]

    proxy:
      type: 'jsonp'
      url: 'http://www.mydomain.com/rest/node'

convertField = (value, record) ->
  console.log value # always "undefined"
  return 'test'
```

Loading the model with a jsonp proxy works, but only the atomic fields (like "nid" and "title") are populated. I tried to add a ["convert" function](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-convert) to the models `body` field, but the `value` parameter is always undefined.

Is there a way to load complex json data into a models field? Or do I have to use the Model-relations system (which would be a lot of mess ...). I also thought about overriding a Ext.data.Reader, but i don't really know where to start.

Comment: What I would do, is look at the `load` event, to access the actual raw info being popped into the store, and play around with it, especially if you don't want a complex relationship set up.

Comment: Did that and found out that the jsonp-type was the problem, since it doesn't add the nodes id to the url. Somehow I assumed that. That resulted in querying only the index, where no fields are fetched (shame on me). Using `type: 'rest'` solves the problem. It won't work across different domains, but I'm working on a phonegap-application anyway, so it doesn't matter.